# Angular binding to async result

Tags: angularjs

I have tried various ways but nothing works for me. What I have:

```
app.controller('someCtrl',
...

$scope.load = function () {
    client.loadAgreements().
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.unapprovedCount = response.data[StatusTypeEnum.Unapproved];
            $scope.approvedCount = response.data[StatusTypeEnum.Approved];

            $scope.$apply();
        });
};
```

Html part:

```
<button text="'({{unapprovedCount}})'" ...
<button text="'({{approvedCount}})'"...
```

When I do:

```
app.controller('someCtrl',
...

$scope.unapprovedCount = 777;

$scope.load = function () {
    client.loadAgreements().
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.unapprovedCount = response.data[StatusTypeEnum.Unapproved];
            $scope.approvedCount = response.data[StatusTypeEnum.Approved];

            $scope.$apply();
        });
};
```

I can see 777 when page renders. However I don't see any updates from promise. Variable is assigned but view is not updated. And if I add apply method then I am getting error:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

What else can I try, as I am new to angular and don't know how to do this?

***EDIT:***

I am not sure if this matters but actually this button uses directive:

```
<button ng-fas-button-with-color-indicator text"'Approved  ({{unapprovedCount}})'" color="red" ...
```

And `text` is rendered in some div.

Comment: did u console the response.data[StatusTypeEnum.Unapproved]

Comment: Sure, in debug mode I see that `$scope.unapprovedCount` is assigned a proper value in `then` part.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
$scope.$apply();
```

from your code and check in your console the value of

```
response.data[StatusTypeEnum.Unapproved]
```

Comment: When I debug I see that `$scope.unapprovedCount` is assigned proper number.

Comment: When load function is called ? Have you got the same issue with approvedCount ?

Comment: Sure, in debug mode I see that `$scope.unapprovedCount` is assigned a proper value in `then` part. If I assign this variable manually some value outside `load` function then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need the `$scope.$apply()`?

**You have to remove it from your code.**

The only need of this function is when you are using a third party lib to manipulate variable from the scope, outside of angular's watch.

When you use apply and the digest cycle is ok, nothing changed, will raise this **error**.

Comment: I am not sure, but when I saw that my view is not updated I googled and I read that angular can not know that my variable changed when async call ended and I need to manually call digest.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri can you post the loadAgreements function?